# Share data in all instance of Android Widget

Tags: android, widget

I am developing a widget which is downloading images from server and show it.When i add widget first ,it is getting download images from server.After if i add another widget,it also try to get images from server.After if i add another widget,it also looking for images from server.I want to shear same data to all widget means 2nd widget to onwards.I was searching for it,did not find any solution.

Comment: Save the image in your sd card after downloading. Then the widget should search for the image in your sd card. If the image exists then it should load the image otherwise download it from your server.

Comment: i was looking for how youtube does.It does not save images sd card??